# I have a graph in matplot lib that shows sin and cos funstions but needs to be formaatted in a specific way

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 11, 1000)
ysin = 2 * np.sin(x)
ycos = 2 * np.cos(x) 

plt.plot(x, ysin, 
         x, ycos, '--')
plt.yticks(np.arange(-4, 5))
plt.grid(color = 'b', alpha = 0.2)
plt.xlabel('X', fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize = 15)
plt.legend(['2sin(x)', '2cos(x)'])
```

And this is the graph it produces:
[Current graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjDwW.png)

This is the graph I need as a fished product:
[Finished graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqQXR.png)

I think I might be getting hung up on the math part more than the code, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter the values depending on whether the derivative is positive or negative:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.linspace(-10, 11, 1000)
ysin = 2 * np.sin(x)
ycos = 2 * np.cos(x)

filter_ysin = np.cos(x) > 0
plt.plot(x, np.where(filter_ysin, ysin, np.nan), label='$2sin(x)$', color='crimson')
plt.plot(x, np.where(~filter_ysin, ysin, np.nan), color='darkgreen')
filter_ycos = -np.sin(x) > 0
plt.plot(x, np.where(filter_ycos, ycos, np.nan), label='$2cos(x)$', ls='--', color='crimson')
plt.plot(x, np.where(~filter_ycos, ycos, np.nan), ls='--', color='darkgreen')
plt.yticks(np.arange(-4, 5))
plt.grid(color='b', alpha=0.2)
plt.xlabel('X', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Y', fontsize=15)
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: curve color depending on derivative]

Comment: Thank you, I never would have thought of that. Works perfectly.